# Why so much drive-by's? What's wrong with Curiosity?

Tags: support, down-votes

I asked a layman question regarding string theory -
[Would string theory change everything?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/37766) several months ago (just a month after joining SE) - when I was completely new to this field.

I definitely accept that it is pretty hard for some rude ***physicists*** here to agree with my *very basic* question. But, I didn't argue, chat or ask something wrong. It just came to my mind. After getting the responses, I just ignored the [string-theory](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string-theory) tag..!

Now, @Skliwz - after enjoying his revision to my post, stated that it isn't understandable. (He didn't respond to me in chat either) Then, Why did he do it? The question should've existed in its old cupboard. What the problem is - I get a lot of downvotes today. I think raged guys are just poking my old questions and downvote it. An example is [Magnetic field lines](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/38561/magnetic-field-lines/38570#38570). I have a thought that these downvotes would continue still.

Do someone have rage or hatred with me? - Please respond now...

Comment: Just to point out, you did ask in the chat at midnight EST on a Saturday before a major holiday. It's completely understandable that somebody may not be online and ready to respond.

Comment: @tpg2114: I know. But, I responded (some 2 hours ago) the instant I saw the revision. I think you've noticed it. When you & Flaw were discussing in chat. Skliwz was also there.

Comment: Crazy Buddy, jsince you are an established member, just re-normalize yourself. However, I agree that driveby downvotes are stupid, especially towards new members. But then again it is easy to say that "this is how things are" than to do something to change this attitude.

Comment: @AntillarMaximus: Um, I agree with that *completely*. I'm experiencing it first. So, I thought those guys could directly deal with me here. Err.. And, thats my mistake. But anyways - Thanks for your response :-)

Comment: Crazy Buddy, I noticed that you voted to close that question. If you're unhappy with the question, why not simply delete it? That will prevent anyone from being able to downvote it...

Comment: @Nathaniel: Err... Hi Nanthaniel. We've got a problem. A question can't be deleted once it gets answers :-)

Comment: @CrazyBuddy oh, I see. I didn't know that.

Comment: @Nathaniel: Well, I've tried many times. I couldn't do that. But, Umm.. These diamond guys could do the *deletion*. They *too* have some limitations I think so :-)

Answer (score 4):

Regarding the question: I've edited it to the point I could understand it, but there were just too many questions there, hence the close vote. It puzzles me that you also voted to close it, so I don't understand the disagreement?

Regarding the down votes: I am not sure what you expect me to say, there? I am not down voting you on purpose, but I did go through the site at length yesterday, cleaning up stuff and voted extensively.

I do not vote based on the person who answers so I don't really know if I voted on your answers and if I did, whether the vote was up or down.

I did not see your ping in chat btw. I would have answered otherwise.

Comment: Ironic getting drive-by down votes on a question where someone randomly accuses me of that. Someone has a sense of humour, hehehe :-)

Comment: Hi Sklivvz, I'm sorry for that. As I didn't get any response from you, I just thought of posting it in meta so that you'd notice it. Your triggering produced some downvotes and I thought it'd continue. At that time, I required *support* as it was my first experience on the drive-bies. Thats all... Regarding the closure thing, - I think I've already told that. When I was new to SE, I don't know about these policies and I was very bad in English (more than now), so I don't recognize what I spit out...

Answer (score 3):

In the end drive by downvotes are just part of the deal with Stack Exchange.

Each user will judge for themselves if a post shows effort is useful and clear or if it fails that standard.

Of course, an excess of attention (good or bad) directed at any single user will trip the vote fraud detection resulting in all votes along that graph edge being invalidated (and potentially attraction moderation).

---

Concerning the old questions, they never become too old to be voted on and users are allowed to use your profile to find yout old stuff. In principle they should, of course, treat each post as an individual artifact and vote the content not the user; but there isn't any mechanism to enforce that beyond the vote fraud detection.

Comment: First, Thanks for your response. But, regarding my down-voted answer - It made me suspicious about something. *"A question gets revision. It gets downvoted. Withing few mins, previous answer gets downed."* Of course, I agree that we can't don anything to such a question than explaining the actual mechanism of the field lines. What do you think of it? Any piece of advice...

Comment: It is worth recalling that edits bump questions on the active queue. If you browse physics.stackexchange.com rather than physics.stackexchange.com/questions then you *see* bumped question again (or for the fist time if you missed them), so an edit followed by a vote is not a sign of a acts in bad faith or a conspiracy: it could just as well be a sign of more attention. You just don't have any guarantee that the attention will be positive.